# Order posts by multiple dimensions in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm attempting to display a list of posts, ordered by multiple dimensions.
First, all posts from the same "series" are to be displayed together, then within those series, the posts are to be ordered by "year".

What I think should work is this:

```
<?php
                
$args =  array(
    'post_type'  => 'books',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'books_series_clause' => array(
            'key'  => 'series',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        'books_year_clause' => array(
            'key'  => 'year',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby'    => array(
        'books_series_clause' => 'DESC'
        'books_year_clause' => 'DESC'
    ),
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
```

However when I run this I get nothing but "There has been a critical error on this website."
I can stop this error by making one of the items under "orderby" into a comment, which only orders the posts by one dimension.
How do I get both to work at the same time?

Comment: You're missing a comma in your `orderby` array, hence the error message.

Comment: perfect! Just needed a second pair of eyes I guess!